# (Silverlight) How to display all elements from TabControl in a new window to print them?

Tags: silverlight, printing, tabcontrol

I would like to display all the informations from my tabs in one place so I could use PrintDocument class to print the content. Is there a way I could gather them in one place to use PrintDocument easily?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried creating a stackpanel and add each tab item as child item in stackpanel.. and then print the stackpanel using printdocument.

Comment: That is a great solution, thank you!

But there is a new problem: when I click the tabitem whose contents I added to my stackpanel, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a deepcopy of the things you want to print: [How do I make a Deep Copy of a UIElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124481/how-do-i-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-uielement)

and add those to a PrintDocument. Also: if you use DataBinding make sure you set the DataContext of the deepcopy correctly.